# Jquery Mobile, Collapsible set and childrens

Tags: jquery-mobile, accordion

I'm trying to populate the content of JQM accordions/collapsible sets dynamically. I've had a look at http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH20.php, but the examples seem to be outdated. So I've tried to come up with a working example, but I'm currently stuck and can't see, why this shouldn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mySet").bind('expand', function (event, ui) {
        /* This prints e.g. "This is the first entry\n
        I'm the collapsible set content for section 1." */
        console.log($(this).text());

        /* This should print "This is the first entry" (=the innerText of <h3>)
        but it doesn't, it prints "This is the first entry\n
        I'm the collapsible set content for section 1." as well */
        console.log($(this).next().text());

        /* This should just print "I'm the collapsible set content for section 1"
        (=the innerText of <p>) but it doesn't, it prints e.g. "This is the 
        first entry\n I'm the collapsible set content for section 1." as well */
        console.log($(this).nextAll("p").text());
    });
});
</script>

<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="mySet">
        <h3>This is the first entry</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="mySet">
        <h3>This is the second entry</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone see, why jQuery won't descend on `$(this)` (=which points to the currently expanded `<div ...class="mySet">`? If I debug this code in Opera's DragonFly I can see, that `$(this)` seems to be the same as `$(this).next()` (at least they have the same values for innerHTML etc.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, after fiddling around a little bit I came up with the following hack/workaround:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mySet").bind('expand', function (event, ui) {
        /* I'm just creating a new var "myDiv" which points to my current div (so in a 
        way "myDiv" is just a copy of "this" */
        var myDiv = $("#"+$(this).attr('id'));
        var myP = myDiv.find('p:first');

        // Works as expected, prints "I'm the collapsible set content for section 1."
        console.log(myP.text());
    });
});
```